# Access wcf service with clientCredentialType="UserName" using soapui

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, client, soapui

I have a WCF service which I'm trying to access using SoapUI. The service is working fine and I'm able to access with a .net client application, but I'm not able to figure out how to access the service using SoapUI. In C# I specify the username and password for the client like this

```
var client = new xxxService.xxxServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxxx";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxx";
```

but how do I specify the client credentials in soapui or in the xml

This is what the request looks in soapui

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetUsers/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add WS-Security Configuration to your request.
Read this http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/applying-ws-security.html

And see the section under "Username". And then in your testsuite in soapUI, be sure to add the ws-security conf you just created. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Soap UI on the bottom left in Request Properties tab double click "Username" and "Password" and changed. You are still getting errors change same tab "WSS-Password Type" PasswordText

Answer (score 0):

In Navigator window in soapUI click on your WSDL item. Second tab 'Service Endpoints' list all endpoints. Second and third columns are Username and Password. Enter your credentials there.